# Pigeonhole Principle Proof Verification

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, pigeonhole-principle

Let $a_1<a_2<\ldots<a_{n+1}$ different integers. Prove that $$n!\Big|\prod_{1\leq i< j\leq n+1}{(a_j-a_i)}$$Here's my proof:

> Let $k\in\bigl\{1,2,\ldots,n\bigr\}$.
> $k<n+1$ and using the Pigeonhole Principle, there are $0\leq i<j\leq n+1$ (but $0\leq i<j\leq k+1$ is enough) such that $$a_i \equiv a_j\pmod{k}$$Thus, $$k\big|(a_j-a_i)$$Every $k\in\bigl\{1,2,\ldots,n\bigr\}$ satisfies this, and we are done.

Is the proof correct? I couldn't find a mistake myself but it seemed weird that the use of the Pigeonhole Principle had $n+1$ pigeons and only $k$ holes (when $k$ can be as little as $1,2,3$). Am I missing something?

Comment: what do you mean by $k\in[n]$? What is $[n]$?

Comment: It's a symbol for $\bigl\{1,2,\ldots,n\bigr\}$. I thought about changing it before as I wasn't sure if it's a known symbol or not. I changed it now though.

Comment: It is very common, at least in combinatorics.

Comment: Then I guess $k<n+1$ is redundant.

Comment: It's wrong. All you have proved is that the lcm of $1,2,...,n$ divides the product of those differences.

Comment: Your proof is not sufficient : you need to prove that the pair $(i,j)$ such that $k\mid (a_j-a_i)$ is different for every $k$. Otherwise with the same reasoning, you could prove that $2^{10} | 2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that your argument shows that
$$
\prod_{1\leq i<j\leq n+1}(a_j-a_i)
$$
(you shouldn't allow $i=j$), which is actually a Vandermonde determinant, is divisible by all $k\leq n$.

This is not (yet) enough to conclude that $n!$ divides it: $3\cdot4\cdot 5=60$ has this property but is actually smaller than $5!$.

---

But it is possible that the argument can be improved upon.

Given a prime $p\leq n<n+1$ there are always $\lfloor\frac n{p^k}\rfloor+1$ elements among the $a_i$'s that give the same class modulo $p^k$ as long as $p^k\leq n$. This should account for the
$$
\lfloor\frac n{p}\rfloor+\lfloor\frac n{p^2}\rfloor+\lfloor\frac n{p^3}\rfloor+\cdots
$$
factors of $p$ that occur in $n!$.

(I leave to you to fill the details)

Comment: +1 Very nice elegance.